# Slope of the tangent of the curve $\cos(x-y)+\sin(x+y)=1$, when $x=y=\pi$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Now I have graphed this online and  get [image]

Now by directly substituting, I get $\cos0+\sin2\pi=1$ which is just
$1=1$.

So what exactly is this question asking?

Comment: The graph seems not the right one: it does not contain $x=y=\pi$

Comment: Yeh i realized afterwards that i didn't snip the right region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{d}{dx}(\cos(x-y)+\sin(x+y))=\frac{d}{dx}(1)$
$-\sin(x-y)\frac{d}{dx}(x-y)+\cos(x+y)\frac{d}{dx}(x+y)=0$
$-\sin(x-y)(1-\frac{dy}{dx})+\cos(x+y)(1+\frac{dy}{dx})=0$
$-\sin(x-y)+\sin(x-y)\frac{dy}{dx}+\cos(x+y)+\cos(x+y)\frac{dy}{dx}=0$
$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\sin(x-y)-\cos(x+y)}{\sin(x-y)+\cos(x+y)}$
At $x=y=\pi,$
Slope of tangent$=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\sin(\pi-\pi)-\cos(\pi+\pi)}{\sin(\pi-\pi)+\cos(\pi+\pi)}=-1$

Answer (score 1):

It is sufficient to use implicit differentiation.

$\frac{d}{dx}\big(\cos(x - y) + \sin(x + y)\big) = \frac{d}{dx} 1$

$-\sin(x - y) + \frac{dy}{dx}\sin(x - y) + \cos(x + y) + \frac{dy}{dx}\cos(x + y) = 0$

$\frac{dy}{dx}\big(\sin(x - y) + \cos(x + y)\big) = \sin(x - y) - \cos(x + y)$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{\sin(x - y) - \cos(x + y)}{\sin(x - y) + \cos(x + y)}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}\vert_{(x,y) = (\pi,\pi)} = -1$